# How to capture Post data from silverlight app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I use Silverlight 3 and .net framework 3.5. I want to send xml data to server on click of a button. On googling i found that we can use WebClient Class's UploadStringAsync method.

I am posting data to a web service running under local IIS. All that is fine but how do i capture the data posted on the service?

Comment: The question sounds a bit odd, you seem to indicate that you have an existing web service but of course you wouldn't be posting to what we understand a web service to be.  The question is poorly tagged you need some asp.net help to code the server end of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code reads the post data which can further be processed.

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
        {
            string t = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Capture for diagnostic/debugging purposes? Try [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: Actually I want to further process the XML and save it with the web service. I am able to submit the data with post but how to capture the data on the web service?